# Replacing a faulty disk in a RAID 5 btrfs filesystem?

Tags: disk, btrfs, troubleshooting

I'm running Rockstor with one of my pools using RAID 5 btrfs - which I know is experimental, I don't think that's the issue here. One disk of the four in the pool is faulty, with 20000+ write I/O errors and roughly 500 read I/O errors.

I installed a new disk in the server and used the Rockstor UI to add the disk to the pool, but it turns out that due to the errors on the faulty disk btrfs forces the filesystem into read-only, which in turn causes the rebalance to fail.

I found information on how to manually replace a disk using the CLI, but the problem now is that btrfs doesn't allow me to remove the new, newly added disk from the filesystem as it's a read-only filesystem.

So, before I make things even worse, I decided to ask for some advice on how to proceed. :)

Can I force btrfs to remove the new disk from the filesystem and then use [a guide like this](https://wiki.tnonline.net/w/Btrfs/Replacing_a_disk) to manually replace the disk? Or is there another way around this?

Comment: what if you simply drop the faulty disk? in RAID5, any single disk can be dropped (as long as the rest is correct)

Comment: Hi Marcus.

I didn't know I could do that if the filesystem is read-only, but maybe I can force btrfs to drop the disk?